# SQl error message for CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling

In the PLSQL script:

```
"open" = SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND remind1_sent.date_value IS NULL

"open_reminder_sent" = SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND remind1_sent.date_value IS NOT NULL

"closed" = SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) <> 'O'
```

When I use the following code:

```
(CASE WHEN status = "SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND remind1_sent.date_value IS NULL" THEN 1 WHEN status = "SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND remind1_sent.date_value IS NOT NULL" THEN 2 WHEN status = "SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) <> 'O'" THEN 3 END) as stata
```

I get the following error message:

```
00972. 00000 -  "identifier is too long"
*Cause:    An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
*Action:   Specify at most 30 characters.
```

How do I resolve this issue please? Thanks

Comment: `"SUBSTR` is invalid. You shouldn't be quoting function calls - remove the double quotes around the `substr()` calls.  Also `"open" = SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND remind1_sent.date_value IS NULL` isn't valid PL/SQL code

Comment: Your PL/SQL script doesn't make sense.  Is `"open"` a local variable?  If so, you're using `=` for assignment rather than `:=`.  Is `"open"` a boolean?  I can't imagine why you'd want to declare a local variable using a case sensitive identifier.  Your `case` statement makes less sense.  You use single quotes to delinate a string, not double quotes.  But I don't think you want even single quotes before `SUBSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want

```
(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND 
           remind1_sent.date_value IS NULL
      THEN 1 
      WHEN SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND 
           remind1_sent.date_value IS NOT NULL 
      THEN 2 
      WHEN SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) <> 'O' 
      THEN 3 
  END) as stata
```

If you are trying to compute both a `status` and a `stata` in the same query and you want the `stata` calculation to be based on the computed `status`, you can use inline views.  Something like

```
SELECT <<columns>>
       CASE WHEN inline_view.status = 'open' THEN 1
            WHEN inline_view.status = 'open_reminder_sent' THEN 2
            WHEN inline_view.status = 'closed' THEN 3
        END stata
  FROM (SELECT <<columns>>
               CASE WHEN SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND 
                         remind1_sent.date_value IS NULL
                    THEN 'open'
                    WHEN SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) = 'O' AND 
                         remind1_sent.date_value IS NULL
                    THEN 'open_reminder_sent'
                    WHEN SUBSTR(arfi_status.prop_value,1,1) != 'O'
                    THEN 'closed'
                 END status
            FROM <<your table>>) inline_view
```